# How to add some dummy values to my existing T-SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have the following T-SQL query:

```
USE MyDatabase
SELECT [Property]
       ,[Pax]
       ,[Mth]
       ,'FY1718' as [ID]
FROM Table1
WHERE [Mth] between '2017-07-01' and '2018-06-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT [Property]
       ,[Pax]
       ,[Mth]
       ,'FY1819' as [ID]
FROM Table2
WHERE [Mth] between '2018-07-01' and '2019-06-01'
```

An extract of the output:

```
Property    Pax   Mth           ID
 TRO        120   2017-07-01    FY1718
 EBC        95    2018-08-01    FY1819
```

I want to create 2 dummy entries with the following values:

```
EBC,  0,  2017-09-01, FY1718
GHY,  0,  2017-10-01, FY1718
```

My final output should look like this:

```
 Property   Pax   Mth           ID
 TRO        120   2017-07-01    FY1718
 EBC        95    2018-08-01    FY1819
 EBC        0     2017-09-01    FY1718
 GHY        0     2017-10-01    FY1718
```

How can I add those lines in the final output?

Comment: UNION ALL...VALUES...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use UNION ALL

```
SELECT [Property]
       ,[Pax]
       ,[Mth]
       ,'FY1718' as [ID]
FROM Table1
WHERE [Mth] between '2017-07-01' and '2018-06-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT [Property]
       ,[Pax]
       ,[Mth]
       ,'FY1819' as [ID]
FROM Table2
WHERE [Mth] between '2018-07-01' and '2019-06-01'
union all
SELECT 'EBC'
       ,0
       ,'2017-09-01'
       ,'FY1819'
union all
SELECT 'GHY'
       ,0
       ,'2017-10-01'
       ,'FY1819'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT [Property],
   [Pax],
   [Mth],
   'FY1718' AS [ID] FROM   Table1 WHERE  [Mth] BETWEEN '2017-07-01' AND '2018-06-01'
UNION ALL
SELECT [Property],
   [Pax],
   [Mth],
   'FY1819' AS [ID]
FROM   Table2
WHERE  [Mth] BETWEEN '2018-07-01' AND '2019-06-01'
UNION ALL       
SELECT *
FROM   (
       VALUES ('EBC', 0, '2017-09-01', 'FY1818'),
       ('GHY', 0, '2017-10-01', 'FY1818')
   ) DummyTable([Property], [Pax], [Mth], [ID])
```